# arc4random_uniform producing very large values when casting to float

Tags: objective-c, casting, floating-point, integer, arc4random

Blank project. Code:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 8) {
    float amount = 100-arc4random_uniform(200);
    NSLog(@"amount: %f", amount);
    i++;
}
```

Log:

```
amount: 21.000000
amount: 90.000000
amount: 79.000000
amount: 4294967296.000000
amount: 39.000000
amount: 4294967296.000000
amount: 81.000000
amount: 4294967296.000000
```

---

4294967296.000000 is clearly outside the range of `100 - ran(200)` (pseudocode)

If I don't declare `amount` as `float` and instead use `int` this doesn't happen.

What's going on here?

Comment: arc4random returns unsigned integer. Cast that to an (signed) integer or double before doing your subtraction.

Comment: @Rob Thank you! Is there any intuitive way to tell when something is going to be signed vs unsigned or do I just have to check the docs. I've had no formal code training and only learned everything I know by reading source code so I don't know the difference between signed and unsigned as of yet; I'm assuming it has to do with the ± *sign* infront of a number (or lack there-of for 'unsigned').

Comment: A standard 32-bit `int` can represent values between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647, but an `unsigned int` can only represent values between 0 and 4,294,967,295 (i.e. 2 raised to the 32nd power, minus 1). So if you subtract 1 from a unsigned int value of 0, since it can't represent -1 it wraps around to 4,294,967,295. Regarding how to know, the only thing I can suggest that is that if you keep the "Quick Help" panel open on the left, it makes it much easier to confirm what type a method returns. And sadly, it's simply incumbent upon you, the developer, to confirm the signedness of a method.

Comment: So whenever you have a method that can't return a negative number (e.g. a function to return a value between 0 and some positive integer), recognize the possibility that it might be unsigned, so make a mental note to check what type it returns (especially when you are writing code that is dependent upon its being signed vs unsigned).

Comment: Good pointer, thanks @Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rob points out, `arc4random_uniform` returns a 32-bit unsigned integer type (`uint32_t`), that is, a number greater than or equal to zero, never negative. The compiler thus evaluates the expression `100-arc4random_uniform(200)` expecting the result also to be an unsigned number.

If the result of `arc4random_uniform(200)` in your example code happens to be greater than 100, then `100-arc4random_uniform(200)` will result in a negative number being assigned to a data type that cannot express negative numbers, so you'll end up with unexpected results.

You can indicate to the compiler that you want to be dealing with signed numbers by, as @rob suggests, casting the result of `arc4random_uniform` to a signed number (in this case a `float`):

```
float amount = 100 - (float)arc4random_uniform(200);
```

...or by indicating that the expression should return a signed number by explicitly making your other argument a signed number:

```
float amount = 100.0f - arc4random_uniform(200);
```